# C# TrimStart() not available to a string A but is available on string B when I set B= A

Tags: c#

VS2022 c# Web API project, and I don't understand why the TrimStart() method isn't available on a string variable. It does appear on a work around.

I have this class:

```
public class MemberField
{
    ....
    protected string _fieldValue = "Not initialized.";
    ....
    public MemberField(..., string fieldValue)
    {
        _fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    public string FieldValue
    {
        get => _fieldValue;
        set => _fieldValue = value;
    }
}
```

This class is inherited by SubjectField:

```
public class SubjectField : MemberField
{ 
    ....
    public SubjectField()
    {
    }

    public SubjectField(..., string fieldValue) : base(..., fieldValue)
    {
    }
}
```

And Subject field is used in an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public SubjectField SubjectField { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Finally, in my working class I have this:

```
public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    ....
    public MyClass(..., SubjectField subjectField, ...)
    {
        SubjectField = subjectField;
    }
    ....
    public string SubjectFieldValue()
    {
        ....
        // The TrimStart method does not appear for FieldValue
        SubjectField.FieldValue; 
        // But the method does appear on string s:
        string s = SubjectField.FieldValue;
        s.TrimStart();
    }

    public static bool DoWork(..., MyOtherClass oc)
    {
        MyClass c = (MyClass)oc;

        c.SubjectFieldValue();
        ....
    }
}
```

Another class calls static method MyClass.DoWork(....), which in turn instantiates a variable of MyClass and calls SubjectFieldValue.
My question relates to the comments in method ***SubjectFieldValue***. Why do I not have TrimStart() available for SubjectField.FieldValue, but it is available for variable s after I assign SubjectField.FieldValue to it?

Comment: Humor me; write `var x = SubjectField.FieldValue.TrimStart();` and compile it. Tell us exactly  the compiler error message

Comment: What do you mean _"Why do I not have TrimStart() available for SubjectField.FieldValue"_? In intellisense or on compilation?

Comment: Caius and Pranav, thanks for taking the time  to review and respond to my post. the issue has resolved itself, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Closing VS 2022 and coming back in resolved this. Intellisense now shows TrimStart and everything compiles, so I am able to have *SubjectField.FieldValue.TrimStart()*. Not sure what was going on with VS, apologies for wasting everyone's time.